# How to rename an existing table?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to create 200+ tables using declarative base on the fly. I learnt it's not possible, so my idea was to create a common table and rename it 200+ times.

```
class Movie(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    release_date = Column(Date)
    name=Column(String)
    __tablename__ = 'titanic'

    def __init__(self, newname,title, release_date):
        self.title = title
        self.release_date = release_date
```

What is the code to change the table name from "titanic" to "wild"?

In Postgresql it is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

I am not finding a solution in sqlalchemy.

There are no foreign keys to this table.

The objective of this question is to rename an existing table thru a solution (if) available in sqlalchemy, not in a purely python way (as mentioned in the other question).

Comment: You should use something like [sqlalchemy-migrate](https://github.com/openstack/sqlalchemy-migrate) or [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to rename a table is to create a new table, dumping the data into it with an `INSERT INTO` statement.

More from the web:

> You must issue the appropriate [`ALTER` statements](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) to your database to change the name of the table. As far as the Table metadata itself, you can attempt to `set table.name = 'newname'`, and re-place the Table object within `metadata.tables` with its new name, but this may have lingering side effects regarding foreign keys that reference the old name.  In general, the pattern is not supported - its intended that a `SQLAlchemy` application runs with a fixed database structure (only new tables can be added on the fly).
>   ([Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/f1D1LBkaWCE/-EEnevLjvRwJ))

Comment: I want to create 200+ tables using declarative base on the fly.I learnt Its not possible.So my idea was to create a common table and rename it 200+ times. Thanks for your idea but it does not fit my project.

Comment: It's important to provide all relevant information in your question.  Please see [mcve] and well as [ask].

Comment: @revoltman You should clearly state any objectives you have _in_ the question, so that people answering can be aware of them as they answer, and take them into consideration. Otherwise, folks will just waste time providing answers that are ultimately of little use to anyone since the objectives seem to keep changing.

Comment: @TimPost I will definitely take care of this next time. Thank you very much for pointing it out.